# Percona mysql-server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster, ubuntu-16.04

Issue: Can't install Percona mysql server.

Platform: Ubuntu 16.04 x64
Server is an Openvz container.

Memory: 1.5GB

installation method

```
apt-get install percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6
```

Source:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Error displayed after installation.

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.6
```

Errors found from mysql log

```
2016-08-05 19:12:42 9926 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-08-05 19:12:42 9926 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-08-05 19:12:42 9926 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-08-05 19:12:42 9926 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-08-05 19:12:42 9926 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-08-05 19:12:42 7fa6fc84f740  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140355177871168 in file ut0mem.cc line 10
InnoDB: Failing assertion: ret || !assert_on_error
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
13:42:42 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running out of memory, please [enable swapfile](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) or adjust my.cnf values to something that fits your memory size. Cut half of every memory value or use something like:

```
key_buffer = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 32K
read_buffer_size = 128K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 128K
net_buffer_length = 2K
thread_stack = 64K
tmp-table-size  = 8M
max-heap-table-size = 8M
innodb-buffer-pool-size = 16M
key_buffer = 8M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
```

Answer (score 0):

As Anubioz suggested it was a memory issue. I increased burstable memory to 2GB and reinstalled the percona-mysql. As mentioned, this was a openvz container. Following are the changes I made to container.

```
vzctl set ctid --vmguarpages 1500M --save
vzctl set ctid --oomguarpages 1500M --save
vzctl set ctid --privvmpages 1500M:2048M --save
```